# GridLayoutManager with full border

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, border, gridlayoutmanager

Having one RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. each row responsible for displaying three item. Expected view is, allong with each item, should be covered with full border without extra bold(4 side equal width).
code for recycler view. Whatever the approach which I have tried and corresponding UI of screen also attaching.

```
    mHomeRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.home_screen_recycler_view);
    mHomeAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, mHomeScreenItem);

    // to provide scrolling functionality to parent
    mHomeRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mHomeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
    mHomeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mHomeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeAdapter);
```

onCreateViewHolder() of adapter class

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
    return HomeItemViewHolder(mLayoutInflater.inflate
    (R.layout.layout_home_child_item, parent, false))
}
```

```
layout_home_child_item.xml code is below

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/child_item_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/one_not_seven_dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/image_select_tag_layout_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_sub_category"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/child_item_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/each_item_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/each_item_dimen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_icon_in_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/result_received_icon_color"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

shape_sub_category.xml as given below

```
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/search_card_margin" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/item_background_border_width"
            android:color="@color/grid_border_clr" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: UI obtained With above code is]

But the expected UI is like below(full covered border with same thickness)

[image: expectation in grid]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is because when in grid item is place next to each other it will occupy the width of each other in some place. So far your approach is right you just need to do is give your recycle view border so that it will match with your items border. Remember the border width for your recycler view is equal to @dimen/item_background_border_width.

Comment: @Abhishek could you please explain how we can give border to recyclerview as you suggested .. ?

Comment: You can't directly apply border to recyclerView. Tho you can achieve this by putting a FrameLayout fitting the RecyclerView Layout and set the border to that FrameLayout. Get my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement was to provide set of content with grid, border of each content should be same thickness as expected screenshot attached above.

I come up with different approach(kind of other logical way) in order to fix this issue with RecyclerView. Here I am describing how I achieved the same.

1. Create full outer border for RecyclerView, below the layout for the RecyclerView and corresponding border drawable.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/home_screen_recycler_view"
       android:background="@drawable/recycler_border"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/send_cmd_round_rect"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/send_cmd_round_rect"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/send_cmd_round_rect"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/send_cmd_round_rect"
       android:clipToPadding="false"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
   ```

recycler_border.xml is like below

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/item_background_border_width"
        android:color="@color/grid_border_clr" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

With above code changes, we can observe outer border for the RecyclerView layout.

2. In-order to provide border for child items, we are going to use GridDividerItemDecoration class. This item decoration class expecting vertical and horizontal drawable and the number of columns in the grid of the RecyclerView.

`Drawable horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_divider);
Drawable verticalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.line_divider);
mHomeRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridDividerItemDecoration(horizontalDivider, verticalDivider, 3));`

line_divider is a custom drawable used to provide line specifications as given below.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<size
    android:width="@dimen/item_background_border_width"
    android:height="@dimen/item_background_border_width" />
<solid android:color="@color/grid_border_clr" /></shape>
```

3. In order to access GridDividerItemDecoration, we need to add dependency in app's build.gradle.

   `compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:simple-item-decoration:1.0.0'`

   The output screenshot is attaching below(width is 0.3 dp)

[image]